# Choosing 2 squares in each row and column of an $9$ by $9$ grid such that no two squares are touching

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Suppose I had a $9 \times 9$ grid and I wanted to mark 2 squares in each row and column such that none of the marked squares are touching diagonally or adjacently. This means that none of the marked squares can share an edge or a corner. How many ways would this be possible, if rotations and reflections are considered distinct?

Suppose I had an $n \times n$ grid and I wanted to mark 3 squares in each row and column such that none of the marked squares are touching diagonally or adjacently. What would the smallest possible value of $n$ be so that this is possible?

When attempting these two problems, I tried to somehow find a pattern in each column, but I could not find any. Does anyone have any solution or insight to these two problems.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because of possible cheating

Comment: Is it possible to close all of this account's questions/close the account? All 4 questions asked are from some sort of entrance test.